# Multiply values from numeric vector by specific values from data frame

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector:

```
> dput(vec_exp)
structure(c(12.344902729712, 6.54357482855349, 17.1939193108764, 
            23.1029632631654, 8.91495023159554, 14.3259091357051, 18.0494234749187, 
            2.92524638658168, 5.10306474037357, 2.66645609602021), .Names = c("Arthur_1", 
                                                                              "Mark_1", "Mark_2", "Mark_3", "Stephen_1", "Stephen_2", 
                                                                              "Stephen_3", "Rafael_1", "Marcus_1", "Georg_1"))
```

and then I have a data frame like the one below:

```
        Name     Nr       Numb
1  Rafael      20.8337  20833.7
2  Joseph      25.1682  25168.2
3  Stephen     40.5880  40588.0
4  Leon       198.7730 198773.0
5  Thierry     16.5430  16543.0
6  Marcus      31.6600  31660.0
7  Lucas       39.6700  39670.0
8  Georg      194.9410 194941.0
9  Mark        60.1020  60102.0
10 Chris       56.0578  56057.8
```

I would like to multiply the numbers in numeric vector by the numbers from the column `Nr` in this data frame. Of course it is important to multiply the values by the name. It means that Mark_1 from numeric vector should be multiplied by the `Nr = 60.1020`, same for Mark_2, and Stephen_3 by `40.5880`, etc.

Can someone recommend any easy solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `match` to match the names after extracting only the first part of the names of `vec_exp`, i.e. extract `Mark` from `Mark_1` etc.

```
vec_exp * df$Nr[match(sub("^([^_]+).*", "\\1", names(vec_exp)), df$Name)]
# Arthur_1     Mark_1     Mark_2     Mark_3  Stephen_1  Stephen_2  Stephen_3   Rafael_1   Marcus_1    Georg_1 
#       NA  393.28193 1033.38894 1388.53430  361.84000  581.46000  732.59000   60.94371  161.56303  519.80162
```

Arthur is `NA` because there's no match in the data.frame.

---

If you want to keep those entries without a match in the data as they were before, you could do it like this:

```
i <- match(sub("^([^_]+).*", "\\1", names(vec_exp)), df$Name)
vec_exp[!is.na(i)] <- vec_exp[!is.na(i)] * df$Nr[na.omit(i)]
```

This first computes the matches and then only multiplies those if they are not NA.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` methods.  Convert the `vector` to a `data.frame` with `stack`, create a 'Name' column by removing the substring from 'ind' and `merge` with the data.frame ('df1').  Then, we can multiply the 'Nr' and the 'values' column.

```
d1 <- merge(df1, transform(stack(vec_exp), Name = sub("_.*", "", ind)), all.y=TRUE)
d1$Nr*d1$values
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, it is much more easier to understand.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
stack(vec_exp) %>%
        separate(ind, into = c("Name", "ind")) %>%
        left_join(., df1, by = "Name") %>% 
         mutate(res = values*Nr) %>% 
        .$res
#[1]         NA  393.28193 1033.38894 1388.53430  361.84000  
#[6]    581.46000  732.59000   60.94371  161.56303  519.80162
```